# Spectral radius of a rank-1 perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

Suppose that $\bf A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ are vectors.  The [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) lets us easily compute the determinant of ${\bf A} + {\bf u} {\bf v}^\top$, while the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) gives us the inverse.  Is there anything at all that can be said about the spectral radius of ${\bf A} + {\bf u} {\bf v}^\top$?  (Any kind of bounds would be a help.)

Comment: A trivial bound is $r\le \|A\|+\|u\|\, \|v\|$, and I doubt that much more can be said in general. In particular, it's definitely not possible to bound $r(A+uv^t)$ in terms $r(A)$ and $\|u\|$, $\|v\|$, as simple examples show.

Comment: Thanks! That's basically my impression too, but figured it was worth a shot.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why $r\le ||A||+||u||||v||$.

Comment: @AlexanderMathiasen I assume it's using the spectral norm as an upper bound. Take a look at the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Christian's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/q/209778/#comment519891_209778), since the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) is upper-bounded by the spectral norm,

$$\begin{aligned} \rho \left( {\bf A} + {\bf u} {\bf v}^\top \right) &\leq \left\| {\bf A} + {\bf u} {\bf v}^\top \right\|_2 \\ &\leq \left\| {\bf A} \right\|_2 + \left\|  {\bf u} {\bf v}^\top \right\|_2 \\ &= \left\| {\bf A} \right\|_2 + \left\|  {\bf u} \right\|_2 \left\| {\bf v} \right\|_2 \end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the simplest case is where the matrix $\bf A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite (PSD) and ${\bf u} = {\bf v}$, which ensures that the eigenvalues of the rank-$1$ update are in $\Bbb R_0^+$. Hence,

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {t \in \Bbb R} {\text{minimize}} & t \\ \text{subject to} & {\bf A} + {\bf u} {\bf u}^\top \preceq  t \, {\bf I}_n \end{array} $$

which, via the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), can be rewritten as the following [semidefinite program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) (SDP)

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {t \in \Bbb R} {\text{minimize}} & t \\ \text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix} t \, {\bf I}_n - {\bf A} & {\bf u}\\ {\bf u}^\top & 1 \end{bmatrix} \succeq {\bf O}_{n+1} \end{array} $$

This is **not** very satisfactory, but it *may* be better than nothing.